# find all .sh files then copy to <date>scriptbackup

Tags: shell-script, files

Locate all the `.sh` scripts you have created in
your Linux installation (searching recursively if
needed – excluding existing backup folders)

It will then copy them all into a folder called
-scriptbackup and archive them as a tar
gzip file

Comment: looks like homework, what have you tried ?

Comment: find -name "*.sh"

Comment: need comand to copy to <%d%m%Y>myscriptbackup

Comment: is is cp <%D%M%Y>myscriptbackup      btw im 40 not homewolk..just trying to learn

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```bash
directory=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)-scriptbackup
#create if it doesn't exist
mkdir -p "$directory"
#find and copy
#replace "." with the directory
#where you want to search for the files,
#if it isn't the same as the current directory
find . -name '*.sh' -exec cp '{}' "$directory" ';'
tar -cvzf "${directory}.tar.gz" "$directory"
```